# Video player Android selection

Tags: android, android-video-player

When trying to play a Video on Android, the app is prompting the user to select the player.

In code, I am doing the following. Is it possible that I select the player so the user wont' be prompted?

```
String url = (String) v.getTag();
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");
            startActivity(intent);
```

Below is the image this is shown to the user: 
[image]

**Edit pasted as answer**

```
intent.setPackage("com.sec.android.app.videoplayer");
```

I take it back. That might cause a problem on some phones. It worked on S4. However,It might not work on others. More work needs to be done.

Comment: its up to the user to make that choice.

Comment: There has to be a hint that you can set in the intent to auto choose that. I am looking for that.

Comment: your app. shouldn't go against the user's wishes.

Comment: It is requirement. 

I found that you can set the package name and that solved my problem ( intent.setPackage("com.sec.android.app.videoplayer");)


Thanks

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent